# A Grönwall-type inequality for $u(t)\le\alpha(t)+\int_0^t\max(u(s),\beta(s))\:{\rm d}s$?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, differential-inequalities

Quick question: Are we able to show a Gronwall-type inequality assuming that $$u(t)\le\alpha(t)+\int_0^t\max(u(s),\beta(s))\:{\rm d}s,$$ where $\alpha$ is nondecreasing (or constant) and $\beta$ is bounded and measurable (or nondecreasing, if this is helpful)?

I'm willing to assume that $\alpha, u$ and $\beta$ are nonnegative.

We can then clearly apply the usual Gronwall inequality after using $\max(u(s),\beta(s))\le u(s)+\beta(s)$, but I'm looking for a sharper inequality.

Comment: Upon the suggestion of a friend of mine, if you add $\beta(t)$ on each side and use the inequality, you can then apply gronwall on $\psi(t) = \max(u(t), \beta(t))$.

Comment: @Theleb Thank you for the suggestion. I guess you're intending to assume that $u$ and $\beta$ are nonnegative, since then $\psi(t)\le u(t)+\beta(t)\le\alpha(t)+\beta(t)+\int_0^t\psi(s)\:{\rm d}s$. Applying Gronwall yields $\psi(t)\le(\alpha(t)+\beta(t))e^t$. But is this result really better than using $u(t)\le\alpha(t)+\int_0^t\beta(s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^tu(s)\:{\rm d}s$, which yields $u(t)\le\left(\alpha(t)+\int_0^t\beta(s)\:{\rm d}s\right)e^t$?

Comment: Yes it is better : the second bound is worse than the first by a factor $t$ for $t$ large.

Comment: One can save a factor of $2$ or so by taking max with $\beta(t)$ rather than summation, thus using $\max(u(t),\beta(t)) \leq \max(\alpha(t),\beta(t)) + \int_0^t \max(u(s), \beta(s))\ ds$ as the starting point (assuming everyone is non-negative).

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you for your comment, but doesn't taking max with $\beta(t)$ yield $\max(u(t),\beta(t))\le\max(\alpha(t),\beta(t))+\max\left(\int_0^t\max(u(s),\beta(s))\:{\rm d}s,\beta(t)\right)$ instead?

Comment: $\max(a+b, c) \leq \max(a, c) +b$ when $a, b, c \geq 0$. ($\max$ is $1$-Lipschitz.)

Comment: @TerryTao Yes, sure, you're right.